# What would be the recommended way to exchange data from a WebGL application running on a Raspberry Pi to write to the Pi's serial interface?

Tags: node.js, express, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, webgl

Here's the full problem:

I have a WebGL build of a Unity project running on a Pi, and I need the data from this process written to the Pi's serial interface (and vice versa).  The best possible solution I can think of is hosting the WebGL server using Express, and utilizing nodejs for the backend process of somehow running some python code that works the serial interface.  Problem is, I'm super inexperienced with these platforms and I don't have enough familiarity with how they all work together to intuitively feel out what to do.  Hoping I can get some guidance on any recommended paths.

Pre answered questions:

Unity project on a Pi?: I have a simulation running in Unity, and I need it running on a lightweight computing platform.  The only way to run this on a Pi is in a WebGL build.

What are you trying to achieve?: I'm trying to achieve a communication pipeline with this WebGL process and an Arduino, specifically over serial.

What I've tried:

I've tried running the WebGL process utilizing systems like Banyan, which would allow communication with a server, but it seems the WebGL build does not allow sockets.

I've tried hosting the server using Express through nodejs, and the app does actually work, I just need help understanding how this system works such that I can exchange data from the WebGL app and a python script that is running the serial comms.  As stated above, I'm very new to the nodejs system so I may not even be using the nomenclature properly.

Comment: Make an api for it running on a webserver on the pi. Also remember webgl runs on your machine not the pi

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks I will look into it.  What do you mean webgl isn't running on the Pi?

Comment: It runs on whatever machine browses the page.

Comment: @BugFinder the pi is the machine that browses the page.  There is nothing else except for the pi.

Comment: Well. That wouldn't be normal to be honest. But it is important for pretty much any one else that the machine browsing the website runs the website eg your pc. Not the machine holding the website. Either way you still need to make an api running on the webserver as browsers due to lots of issues in the past get restricted from what they can do